# Определить какая дата из массива находится ближе всего к введенной дате

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть массив дат, каждой дате поставлено в соответствие определенное значение параметра. Пользователь вводит дату и надо определить значение параметра, дата которого находится ближе всего к введенной дате. Единственное что приходит в голову это использовать массив кортежей `List<Tuple<T1, T2>>`, в котором хранить параметр и разницу между датами (датой параметра и введенной датой) и затем отсортировать и взять первое значение. Возможно есть более красивый способ? Спасибо.

Comment: а зачем сортировать всё? Вам по сути только минимальный нужен.

Comment: Отсортировать массив дат, потом найти, между какими двумя элементами окажется введенная дата, затем двумя сравнениями выбрать из них ближайшую дату. Алгоритмическая сложность та же (`O(N*log(N)) + O(log(n)) + O(1) = O(N*log(N))`), но логика, имхо, будет попроще.

Comment: Какая сортировка? Какие O(N*log(N))? Просто пройти по списку, O(N).

Comment: @Yaant а если введенная дата выйдет за полученный диапазон?

Comment: @andreycha Да, что-то меня занесло в ненужные дебри. Но если известно, что исходный массив уже отсортирован, тогда можно обойтись и логарифмом. :)

Comment: @e1s Ну, выйдет, и выйдет, в чем, собственно, проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как верно заметили, сортировка не нужна. Быстрее будет пробежаться по всем элементам, на ходу вычисляя самый близкий. Ну и не забудьте про приведение дат к UTC, например, если они у вас из разных поясов.

```
var data = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>()
{
    { DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), -2 },
    { DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), -1 },
    { DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), 3 },
};

var specifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

var distances = data
    .Select(p => new { Distance = Math.Abs((specifiedDate - p.Key).Ticks), p.Value });

var distance = long.MaxValue;
int closestParameter;
foreach (var pair in distances)
{
    if (pair.Distance < distance)
    {
        distance = pair.Distance;
        closestParameter = pair.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Используй Linq, Люк... :)

```
var RawData = new List<DateTime> ()
{
   { DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) },
   { DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
   { DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)  }
}
var specifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

var minDistance = RawData.Min(n => (n - specifiedDate).Duration());
var minDate = RawData.Where(n => (n - specifiedDate).Duration() == minDistance).ToList();
```

Comment: Это не вполне верно. Это выдаст минимальное _расстояние_, а нужна по идее _дата_ с минимальным расстоянием.

Comment: Ок, обернем в еще один фильтр.

Answer (score 5):

Ну и в качестве варианта, моя любимая функция `MinBy` из пакета [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/):

```
using MoreLinq;

// ...

var dict = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>()
{
    [new DateTime(2016, 1, 1)] = "прошедший Новый Год",
    [new DateTime(2016, 12, 31)] = "будущий Новый Год",
    [new DateTime(2014, 1, 5)] = "давным-давно"
};
var today = DateTime.Now;
var closestValue = dict.MinBy(kvp => (kvp.Key - today).Duration()).Value;
// -> будущий Новый Год
```